# Perl version of php's memory_get_peak_usage

Tags: perl, memory

Is there something in perl similar to PHP's [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)? For example, in PHP I can stick in the line:

```
echo "Peak memory usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MB\r\n";
```

and it does pretty much what it says. I need a way to get the same sort of information in a perl script.

I should note that this for a CGI script, and based on a shared webhost - not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek). The `mstat` function prints a large number of memory statistics at any point you like.

Alternately you can call your perl script with the `PERL_DEBUG_MSTATS` environment variable set:

```
PERL_DEBUG_MSTATS=2 perl myscript.pl
```

See [this article](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perldebguts-perlmemory.html) for information on how to decipher these statistics.